# Stuck with not working mix of data and procedure polymorphism using inheritance

Tags: inheritance, fortran, polymorphism

i have recently tried to bring some new fortran 2003 features into my code. Basically i want to use a mix of data and procedure polymorphism. After reading a basic tutorial about these concepts (Object-Oriented Programming in Fortran 2003
Part 1: Code Reusability: https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n1a3.htm and
Object-Oriented Programming in Fortran 2003
Part 2: Data Polymorphism https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n2a2.htm) i tried to get my basic concept to work.

The idea is that i have a basic type `interaction`, which has a name and some type-bound procedures. Then i have some specific interactions like `smallso2inv`, which extend the interaction type by some parameters and override the type-bound procedures of the basic type. Now i want to pass the initialize Method of the basic type an interaction name like

```
call interaction%initialize("smallso2inv")
```

and the internal pointer `specInteraction` should then point to the type `smallso2inv`. When using now

```
call interaction%readInit()
```

i want the readInit routine from the type smallso2inv to be called. This populates the `smallso2inv` type with the parameters needed for calculation.

Here a tiny working example of my interaction module with the mentioned types and my current implementation:

```
module mod_interaction
implicit none
  public
  type interaction
   character*80 :: name                                                     
   class(interaction), pointer :: specInteraction => null()
   procedure, pass(this) :: readInit
   procedure, pass(this) :: readUpdate
   procedure, pass(this) :: compute
   procedure, pass(this) :: addToHamiltonian
   procedure, pass(this) :: updateParameter
  end type interaction

  type, extends(interaction) :: smallso2inv                                                                                          
   double precision :: uvalue, j1value, j2value
   double precision :: uincr, j1incr, j2incr
   contains
   procedure, pass(this) :: setup => smallso2inv_initialize
   procedure, pass(this) :: readInit => smallso2inv_readInit
   procedure, pass(this) :: readUpdate => smallso2inv_readUpdate
   procedure, pass(this) :: compute => smallso2inv_compute
   procedure, pass(this) :: addToHamiltonian => smallso2inv_addToHamiltonian
   procedure, pass(this) :: updateParameter => smallso2inv_updateParameter
  end type smallso2inv

contains

 subroutine initialize(this,name)              
   implicit none               
   type(interaction) :: this
   character*80 :: name
   class(interaction), allocatable, target :: thisInteraction
   !
   select case(name)
    case('smallSO2inv')
     allocate(smallso2inv::thisInteraction)
     call thisInteraction%setup()
     this%specInteraction => thisInteraction
   end select

 end subroutine initialize

 subroutine smallso2inv_initialize(this)
  !
  class(smallso2inv) :: this
  !              
  this%uvalue = 0.0d0
  this%j1value = 0.0d0
  this%j2value = 0.0d0
  print*, "hallo smallso2inv init"              
 end subroutine smallso2inv_initialize

 subroutine readInit (this)
  class(interaction) :: this
  character*80 :: name        
  call this%specInteraction%readInit()             
 end subroutine readInit

 subroutine smallso2inv_readInit(this)
  !
   class(smallso2inv) :: this
   !
   print*, "hello smallso2inv readInit"
   !
  end subroutine smallso2inv_readInit

end module mod_interaction
```

I'm stuck now with two errors using ifort 15.0.0.

```
error #6437: A subroutine or function is calling itself recursively.   [READINIT]

call this%specInteraction%readInit()

error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure.   [SETUP]

call thisInteraction%setup()
```

My implementation seems to try to call the subroutine from the basic `interaction` type instead of using the `smallso2inv` type. Is there a way to fix this without going to case type switches in the `readInit` subroutine? I think this should be possible but somehow i think i mixed up the usage of pointers and variables as my understanding of pointers in the polymorphic context is still limited.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't use the tag `fortran2003` alone. There is a very small number of subscribers for it. And from reading your post there is nothing specific to f2003 that is not also in f2008 so I retagged just to `fortran`

Comment: thank you for that remark. I will account for it in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive complaint is (in my view) a compiler bug[1].  The compiler, at compile time, cannot know, in the general case, which specific procedure the readInit binding will dispatch to, and the restriction around recursive invocation is an execution concept (i.e. at runtime). The simple workaround is to just give in and add the recursive attribute.

You can only access bindings (and components) of the declared type of the object.  One option is to declare the "temporary" object (note you have an object lifetime issue - hence I make the temporary a pointer below) with the required type, or you can use an structure-constructor-like-function as suggested by Vladimir F.  For simple construction the function approach is typical, however if the construction procedure needs to pass back more than just the constructed object (failure flags or similar), then using a local temporary object may be more suitable.

```
subroutine initialize(this,name)              
  implicit none               
  type(interaction) :: this
  character(80) :: name
  !
  select case(name)
   case('smallSO2inv')
    block
      ! Local pointer of the required type.
      type(smallso2inv), pointer :: thisInteraction
      ! Allocate an object of that type and point the pointer at it.
      allocate(thisInteraction)
      ! Initialize the object.
      call thisInteraction%setup()
      ! Save the pointer.
      this%specInteraction => thisInteraction
    end block
  end select
 ...
```

This may be more a style issue, but in the above there is no real point to invoking the `smallso2inv_initialize` procedure through the `setup` binding as the object with the binding isn't polymorphic (so its dynamic type and its declared type are the same) - you could just call the procedure directly.

You should also consider whether the component and temporary need to be a pointer - if the component is not being used as a reference then make them both allocatable (use MOVE_ALLOC to transfer from the temporary to the polymorphic component).

[1]: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/286107 is similar.

Comment: So do you think `call this%specInteraction%readInit()` actually would call `smallso2inv_initialize` at runtime just like i want and this recursive error is just a compiler bug? Or do i need to employ again a select type switch in `readInit`? I think even when using the structure-constructor-like-function there is no way around such select type switch inside `readInit`. Am i wrong?

Comment: No - a call to `this%specInteraction%readInit`, when the dynamic type of `this%specInteraction` is of type `smallso2inv` would invoke `smallso2inv_readInit`.  You don't show the code for that procedure so I have no idea what it ultimately does.  Are you getting the names of the bindings and procedures mixed up?  It depends on the specifics of what you are trying to do, but no - I don't think you need SELECT TYPE.  But context matters.  It is better to ask specific questions with all detail as questions.

Comment: added the routine `smallso2inv_readInit`. This is so far a dummy routine, however in the future it will contain a read from file routine, which will read the needed parameters for the other subroutines of `smallso2inv` like `compute`. These parameters are specific ones for `smallso2inv`. So each type, which extends `interaction` has its own `readInit` routine, as different sets of parameters are read in. Hope this improves the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there will be more errors, but this one is the reported one:

The initialize calls itself. It doesn't matter it calls it with a different object instance. It has to be `recursive`.

```
 recursive subroutine readInit (this)
  class(interaction) :: this 
  call this%specInteraction%readInit()             
 end subroutine readInit
```

The other error is with the initialization. You need to use `select type` typeguard. Inside the `type is` region you can consider `thisInteraction` to have the new non-polymorphic type. You can also use `class is` instead. Whether it is a wise design choice I am not sure. I would personally go for 2 separate procedures, probably functions overloading the type name.

```
 subroutine initialize(this,name)              
      ...
   select case(name)
    case('smallSO2inv')
     allocate(smallso2inv::thisInteraction)
     select case (thisInteraction)
       type is (smallso2inv)
         call thisInteraction%setup()
         this%specInteraction => thisInteraction
     end type
   end select

 end subroutine initialize
```

Note the `character*n` notation is quite obsolete and there is no reason to use `= 0.0d0` instead of the simple `= 0` if you don't have any special user defined assignments.

Comment: Hmm. I dont understand your answer. I need to have `class(interaction) :: this` as the passed object is from this type. My idea was to use `this%specInteraction` to access the proper base type extension (in this case smallso2inv). Note that there is no subroutine setup as `procedure, pass(this) :: setup => smallso2inv_initialize`. I think the compiler ignores      `allocate(smallso2inv::thisInteraction)`
`this%specInteraction => thisInteraction` and stick to the base type for a reason i would like to know.

Comment: I reworked the answer to the first error. I read your intent wrong in the first time. Still the overall design looks dubious to me.

Comment: The compiler doesn't ignore anything. You HAVE TO use the type guard `select type` as I showed, otherwise the compiler still sees the declared type `class(interaction)`, not the dynamic type.

Comment: My first comment was to your unedited answer :). The use of the `select type` statement fixed the second error. Thank you. Note the routine getting called recursively is `readInit` and not `initialize`. So when i understood you correctly i have to use the `select type` statement also in `subroutine readInit`? Is there no way around it? Basically these `select type` switches look dubious to me from object oriented perspective. In my understanding polymorphism is the solution to get rid of them. But apparently not in fortran.

Comment: `Select type` has to be used anywhere where you need to work with a different type than the *declared type*. If you want proper OOP without them use dynamic dispatch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch and type bound procedures and overloading of them. That's why I offered you to have `smallso2inv_initialize` and `interaction_initialize`.

Comment: Note that, for example, in C++ you also have to use various type of casts to work with pointers to different classes. See `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. Do you have a reference, where i can see an example of dynamic dispatch implemented in fortran ? Does this work without any case switches (neglecting the one for basic initialization) ?

Comment: See example on p. 19 in https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/servlet/JiveServlet/download/1470-2-1658/Inheritance.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66043/discussion-between-malte-behrmann-and-vladimir-f).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this slightly changed setup works (just as reference for users browsing this question):

```
module mod_interaction
implicit none
  public
  type interaction
   character*80 :: name                                                  
   class(interaction), pointer :: specInteraction => null()
   procedure, pass(this) :: readInit
   procedure, pass(this) :: readUpdate
   procedure, pass(this) :: compute
   procedure, pass(this) :: addToHamiltonian
   procedure, pass(this) :: updateParameter
  end type interaction

  type, extends(interaction) :: smallso2inv                                                                                          
   double precision :: uvalue, j1value, j2value
   double precision :: uincr, j1incr, j2incr
   contains
   procedure, pass(this) :: initialize => smallso2inv_initialize
   procedure, pass(this) :: readInit => smallso2inv_readInit
   procedure, pass(this) :: readUpdate => smallso2inv_readUpdate
   procedure, pass(this) :: compute => smallso2inv_compute
   procedure, pass(this) :: addToHamiltonian => smallso2inv_addToHamiltonian
   procedure, pass(this) :: updateParameter => smallso2inv_updateParameter
  end type smallso2inv

contains

  subroutine initialize(this,name)
    !
    implicit none
    !
    type(interaction) :: this
    character*80 :: name
    class(interaction),allocatable, target :: thisInteraction
    !
    this%name = name
    select case(name)
    case('smallSO2inv')
       allocate(smallso2inv::thisInteraction)
       select type (thisInteraction)
       type is (smallso2inv)
          call thisInteraction%initialize()
          this%specInteraction => thisInteraction
       end select
    end select
    !           
    !
  end subroutine initialize

 subroutine smallso2inv_initialize(this)
  !
  class(smallso2inv) :: this
  !              
  this%uvalue = 0.0d0
  this%j1value = 0.0d0
  this%j2value = 0.0d0
  print*, "hallo smallso2inv init"              
 end subroutine smallso2inv_initialize

  recursive subroutine readInit (this)
    class(interaction) :: this
    class(interaction), allocatable :: thisInteraction
    character*80 :: name
    !
    call this%specInteraction%readInit()
    print*, "name=",this%name
    !
  end subroutine readInit

 subroutine smallso2inv_readInit(this)
  !
   class(smallso2inv) :: this
   !
   print*, "hello smallso2inv readInit"
   print*, "uvalue=",this%uvalue
   !
  end subroutine smallso2inv_readInit

end module mod_interaction
```

Vladimir F answer proved very helpful to get my `initialize` routine to work and IanH answer was very helpful to get `readInit` routine to work. Some comments to this solution. This works defintely with ifort 15.0.0 other compilers not tested so far. `specInteraction` has to be a pointer, as in ifort 15.0.0 a `type interaction` must not contain an allocatable class of the same type (not implemented feature). Like IanH remarked `readInit` has to be recursive although the right object of type `smallso2inv` is called at runtime, the compiler does not know its type at compile time. That's also the reason why type bound procedure overloading is critical here, as each called procedure has to be found also in the base class `interaction` at compile time. Thanks to both of you for your great help.